# Storing passwords on your phone?

Tags: applications, password

I'm considering switching to a service/app like 1Password, Keepass, LastPass, etc. but before deciding on which to use, I was wondering if anyone else had experience with one of these services and using it on their Android phone?

Ideally, I'm looking for something that is very accessible to use on my phone.

Comment: Sure I remember answering a question on here before where I recommended SplashID, but can't find it, maybe it was never migrated from gadgets?

Comment: Ahh found it, was on ForceClose, hadn't realised it was that long ago http://www.forceclose.com/questions/2360/what-is-the-best-password-manager

Answer (score 8):

I use [LastPass](http://www.appbrain.com/app/lastpass-for-premium-customers/com.lastpass.lpandroid) and the [Dolphin Browser Add-on](http://www.appbrain.com/app/lastpass-for-dolphin-hd-%2aprem/com.lastpass.lpdolphin) on my phone and the [desktop app](https://lastpass.com/misc_download.php) with Chrome and FF extensions on my computer.  I really like the way it works on the desktop.  With the Dolphin Add on it is very easy to fill in login info, however there is no easy prompt to save the password like there is on the desktop version (and like the Dolphin Browser does by default).

The other drawback is that I have set a very complicated master password which is a pain to type in Android.  I have set lastpass to save my master so it's pretty easy to use but not as secure.  The main app has a cool feature that lets you set a pin for the mobile use but this doesn't translate over to the Dolphin Extension.

The other benefit to LastPass is that they just bought Xmarks which is a good service, and I like keeping things consolidated when I can.

Comment: Another vote for LastPass, which I just started using recently.  They have a great series of videos on their site, letting you experience most aspects of the service without installing anything.  I haven't used the Dolphin Browser add-on yet; I'm just using the LastPass app to look up passwords as needed.  It has a feature to copy the password to the clipboard so if you're using it all on the phone, it's easy enough to use without the browser add-in.  It's also easy to generate random passwords that are secure and non-onerous to type if you're often typing them into a browser on a foreign PC.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using Keepass with Dropbox (just put your Keepass file in a Dropbox folder).  It's worked well so far, but I haven't been using it on Android for long.

Comment: Same here, and that way you have everything synced with your desktop machines too (linux and windoze)

Comment: You might want to reconsider. Dropbox mobile clients do not use HTTPS. http://lifehacker.com/#!5781788/dropbox-mobile-apps-less-secure-than-the-desktop-utility

Answer (score 4):

[SplashID](http://www.splashdata.com/splashid/android/) is outstanding.  I like it because it has a desktop component, so you can easily manage your passwords on a human-sized keyboard.  Synchs with Droid when both are on the same wi-fi network.  Is very accessible on the phone too.

Comment: +1 I've been a happy SplashID user right from when I got it for my new (at the time) Palm III. The Android version does WiFi sync with a desktop client, the password database is 256-bit Blowfish encypted. Available on the Market http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-splashidandroid-pnq.aspx

Comment: I like the looks of this.  I'm going to have to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I use SplashId. Used if for many years with my PALM diveces - different models. And when I was looking for a program to keep my passwords with me on my phone, I was very pleased that SplashData had an Android version so I was able to keep my complete list of passwords !

All in all this tells me that this company is a) still in business - for many years now, and b) they follow the market and operating systems - a big plus if you ever switch device.

And the fact that they have a Windows desktop program with a very cool synchronization build in, makes it even better. The synchro works so easy, you turn on Wifi, you start the program both on the desktop and on the phone, and choose syncro.

The android version will recognize the SplashId program running on the PC. In fact, yt will show a list of all PC's running the desktop version of SplashId. You select the PC name in the list on the phone, and press synchro. All in all , very quick and very easy.

That's is how such a system should be.

Answer (score 0):

[Roboform also has an Android client](http://www.roboform.com/platforms/mobile/android) which allows you to login to sites from within the native Android browser. The caveat however, is that you must store your credentials on the Roboform servers using their [Roboform Online service](https://online.roboform.com/).

> There is currently no edit or update
>   ability within the application. This
>   is a high priority to add in a future
>   update.

Answer (score 0):

[PassPack mobile](https://www.passpack.com/mobile/#0) isn't a standalone app, but a nice mobile interface to your existing Passpack account.

I use passpack all the time on the desktop, but haven't really gotten used to using it in my phone's browser.